# Can I unload com.apple.mrt via launchd or otherwise remedy these errors?

Tags: launchd, malware, macos

I just realized that the job `com.apple.mrt` crashes every 10 seconds on my Mac.

- What exactly is the aim of `com.apple.mrt`? Apparently it should be a "Malware Removal Tool".
- Can I remove it from `launchd` (`overrides.plist`) ?

**Here is my Console system.log :**

```
31/07/2015 16:22:11,756 smd[180]: Could not remove job "com.apple.mrt": 150: Operation not permitted while kernel is in rootless mode
31/07/2015 16:22:11,769 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mrt[590]) Service exited with abnormal code: 2
31/07/2015 16:22:11,769 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mrt) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

**Config :**

- MacBook Pro *(13" - mi-2012)*
- 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
- OS X Le Capitan 10.11 *(Beta 4 - build: 15A244d)*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rid yourself of `com.apple.mrt`, you can run a few Terminal commands to get it out of your hair.

First, open the Terminal app. You can find it in Launchpad or by using Spotlight. Next, stop the process using `sudo launchctl stop com.apple.mrt`.

Then, remove the components, using the following (or manually remove them in Finder):

```
sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mrt.plist
sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.mrt.uiagent.plist
sudo rm /System/Library/CoreServices/MRTAgent.app
sudo rm /usr/libexec/MRT
```

Finally, reboot your machine. `com.apple.mrt` should no longer launch on startup (or at all).

**Notes:**

- You may need to enter an administrator's user and password.
- Apple may release updates which re-add `com.apple.mrt` to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

MRT runtime files are not easy deleted.

1. step (Run recovery mode):
   1.1 restart your mac
   1.2 press cmd+r on load
   1.3 recovery mode opened
2. Use Terminal un utilites menu
   2.1. try command `csrutil disabled` (google about csrutil)
   2.2. if you see message "command not found" go to nex step
   2.3. using filesystem delete these files

   `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mrt.plist
   /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.mrt.uiagent.plist
   /System/Library/CoreServices/MRTAgent.app
   /System/Library/CoreServices/MRT.app
   /usr/libexec/MRT`

I input such commands:
 `cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/LaunchDaemons"`
 `rm ./com.apple.mrt.plist`

Important: Macintosh HD - your general bootable disk.

2.4. Restart your Mac
2.5. Enjoy